# Salt Internals, connections from master to minion

Tags: salt-stack, configuration-management

I just have a question I can't figure out about saltstack. It concerns the mater and the minion configuration.

Salt is even driven, but the documention says (and it works) we should only open port on the master, and that event are received on the master.

However it seems a little ambiguous as the **salt** command is run from **master** to execute task on **minions**. But I'm unsuccessfuly trying to understand how the master does that, and I can't a clear documention about it.

And we also have these statements in salt documention [architechure](https://saltstack.com/saltstack-architecture/) :

More Salt Master facts:

- Job publisher with pub/sub and reply channel;
- Two open ports on master (default 4505 / 4506);
- Salt Mine stores the most recent miniondata, cached data is visible
  to other minions;
- Salt Syndic passes jobs from a higher master for hierarchal system
  management;
- Multi-master for SaltStack high availability.

and this

- More Salt Minion facts: Listens and receives jobs from a remote Salt
  Master;
- Creates and reports compressed events (job results, system alerts) to
  the Salt Master;
- No open ports, not chatty;
- Shares data with other Salt Minions via the peer system;
- Returners deliver minion data to any system (Salt Master by default)
  that can    receive the data.

I've highlighted what is ambiguous for me in the attached screenshot.

[image]

The question beeing how can we say the **no port** is to be opened on the **minions** and also say **minions** are listerning from **master**?
**Minions** listen on what? To what?

Thanks for clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question here. By default, Salt uses a zmq pub/sub interface. So there is a slight mismatch between what's literally happening on the network and most people's mental model of how Salt works.

The zmq connection just needs those 2 ports on the Salt master to allow for the pub/sub interface to work. The minion reaches out to the master on pub port. Zmq just handles all the necessary network communication for you. The Salt Master "publishes" jobs on the pub port.

As far as a mental model of how Salt works, it's helpful to think of the minion "listening" on the pub port and executing commands when the Salt Master publishes a job on the pub port when the minion matches the job target.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems more clear for me now, and I understand all the network abstraction is in zeromq